# Functions of Several Variables - Successive Differentiation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am struggling with this question:

Regarding u and v as functions of x and y and defined by the equations : 
$$ x=e^u \cos(v) $$
$$ y=e^u \sin(v) $$

show that :

$$\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2} +\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial y^2}= e^{-2u}  \left( \frac{\partial^2z}{\partial u^2} +\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial v^2}\right)$$

where $z$ is a twice differentiable function of u and v

Much thanks.

Comment: Note that the left hand side is the Laplacian in Cartesian coordinates. Now compare the right hand side is to the Laplacianin Polar coordinates. Here we have  $r=e^u$. The Laplace equation in polar coordinates is  $u_{rr} + \frac{1}{r} u_r + \frac{1}{r^2} u_{\theta\theta}$. So it looks like you have to show $\frac{1}{r^2}z_{uu}=u_{rr} + \frac{1}{r} u_r$

Answer (score 1):

One trick is writing, $$\zeta=e^{w}=f(w)$$

where $\zeta=x+yi$ and $w=u+vi$.

Using Cauchy-Riemann relation,

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}$$

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}=-\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$$

we can derive

$$\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}=|f'(w)|^2$$

So
$$|f'(w)|^2
\left(
  \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}
\right)=
\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u^2}+\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial v^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following tedious work, you may prove it. 
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$$