# What is the equivalent of Integral Formula for change of variables when they are complex?

Tags: calculus

We have in real coordinates the absolute value of the jacobian in the integral formula what is the same thing in complex variables?

Comment: i mean coordinate transformation when the variables are complex.

Comment: Don't know whether the followings are relevant:  [**link 1**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2055276/change-of-variables-in-complex-integration/2055309#2055309) and [**link 2**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851435/functions-of-several-variables-successive-differentiation/1852107#1852107).